# Test scenarios to demonstrate SQL tuning strategies

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance

Is there a place where we can find test cases to illustrate different SQL tuning strategies? For example if the clustering factor on a table is bad and oracle performs a table scan instead of index access I would like to have a test scenario with required data to demonstrate the  bad clustering.
Similarly scenarios to illustrate wrong join order, partitioning and other tuning topics would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing you'll probably find are the numerous tests Jonathan Lewis has written about these topics.

I'd go visit and search his blog: http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/
and/or buy his book: http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/cbo_book/ind_book.html

For example your first question about the clustering factor is covered in chapter 5 of this book, of which you can see a preview [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=TGSd3pkMx5IC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=clustering+factor+sample+chapter+cost+based+fundamentals&source=bl&ots=9k2fgnl6co&sig=_NFwIZY9BQdj3of_VN8olx3Ywso&hl=nl&ei=Rg1lTdj7A4-hOurfrNUF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Exactly what I was writing.  I'd also note that on the book page there is a link to a downloadable set of scripts for reproducing various tuning issues described in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Kyte has many good complete examples on his site: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1:0

Although you'll have to dig them out of the discussion threads